# L4.2 : Extending the class that extends \TestBase

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

I am doing this in my code:

```
class UserTestBase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
```

which includes a few constants to use in my tests.

However, when I `class UserTest extends \UserTestBase`, I receive the following message: `Fatal error: Class 'UserTestBase' not found in...`

```
/**
     * UserTest setUp().
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * UserTest tearDown().
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this on top of your file :

```
use [your-file-namespace]/UserTestBase;
```

Then you will be able to do :

```
class UserTest extends UserTestBase
```